# Clicking Text Element in Tween Halts Animation

Tags: actionscript-3, text, animation, tween

I've been having some trouble with tweens. Here's a description of my usage:

I have a system where a textbox is the child of a movieclip. When you click the "Next" button, the movieclip fades to 0-alpha and upon completion, the text in the textbox is changed (to the next index in an array) and it tweens back in to 100-alpha. This makes a nice transition through the text.

My issue is that sometimes it doesn't tween back in, only out, leaving the user with an empty box where text should be.

However, I'd asked this question previously with the thought that it was "Timing out". Now, after significant testing I realised that it only happens if I click or select some of the text on the text box. Could it have something to do with this text selection intefering with the changeText function below... (it's the same text box, just the text changes).

Has anyone else experienced similar faults?

CODE:

```
function changeClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (e.currentTarget==btnRight) {
        newDirect="right";
    } else {
        newDirect="left";
    }
    if (newDirect=="right") {
        if (pageTotal!=pageCurrent) {
            tweenText=new Tween(b_textB,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,.5,true);
            tweenText.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, changeText);
        }
    } else {
        if (pageCurrent!=1) {
            tweenText=new Tween(b_textB,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,.5,true);
            tweenText.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, changeText);
        }
    }
}

function changeText(e:TweenEvent):void {
    var newText:String;
    var pageCurrentConstant:int=pageCurrent;
    if (newDirect=="right") {
        for (var i=0; i<=(pageTotal-1); i++) {
            if ((pageCurrentConstant-1)==i) {
                if (i!=pageTotal-1) {
                    newText=pageText[i+1];
                    pageCurrent++;
                } else {
                    newText=pageText[i];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var j=0; j<=pageTotal; j++) {
            if (pageCurrentConstant==j) {
                if (j!=0) {
                    newText=pageText[j-2];
                    pageCurrent--;
                } else {
                    newText=pageText[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    b_textB.htmlText=newText;
    tweenText=new Tween(b_textB,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,.5,true);
    drawWidget();
}
```

changeClick is initiated by either btnRight or btnLeft to navigate through the text

Comment: Added a workaround fix for the problem.

Comment: Sorry mate, I have to award it manually, I'll do it now - glad you reminded me actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the text selection, with `b_textB.selectable = false`

You will be able to quickly rule out the possibility of a selection issue. But the *sometimes* in your question strongly indicates that's what the issue is.

If you need the text to be selectable when it's visible, just switch it off and on at the start and end of the tweens.

Hope this solves it.

Oh by the way, here's a list of several completely free alternatives to the **Tween** class... (Greensock's Tween packages are not free.)

- [Between AS3](http://fluxdb.fluxusproject.org/libraries/22-betweenas3)
- [Desuade Motion](http://fluxdb.fluxusproject.org/libraries/218-desuade-motion-package) ... This one in particular is awesome.
- [Tweener](http://fluxdb.fluxusproject.org/libraries/122-tweener)
- [Tweensy](http://fluxdb.fluxusproject.org/libraries/221-tweensy)
- [Twease](http://fluxdb.fluxusproject.org/libraries/125-twease)

### Update...

The only way you can solve this and allow the user to select the text, is to make a duplicate `textfield` that's selectable, and toggle `visible` off for this when the tween begins and on again when it ends, the `alpha` property on the effected `textfield` will then work properly.

Pretty kludgy I know, but it will get the effect to work, and allow the user to select the text when it's visible.

You may also try to wrap the original `textfield` in a `Sprite` and do the `alpha` Tween on that instead, however I don't guarantee that will be a 100% fix.

Comment: I've set b_textB.selectable = false for an intermediary solution, which fixed the problem, but the client needs the text to be selectable. It didn't occur to me to turn it on and off before and after the tween. I'll try that now and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I also tried to (prior to the tween) setSelection(0,0) to cancel any selection made, but unfortunately it gives the same effect, for now I'll keep the selectable property to false.

Comment: It is kludgy I agree, but if I do it all through calling functions etc I can tidy it up a bit. Thanks for your solution +100 to you :)

Comment: Well i can not understand what do u mean by that Greensock's Tween packages are not free?? I am using this library..

Comment: Infact Greensock's library is the best among all.. Tween Class should be deprecated by Adobe. Tween Class has many problems but i have tweeed many objects using Greensock library, it never gets hang.

Comment: @Muhammad - http://www.greensock.com/licensing/ You should be aware of this.  I honestly don't care what tween library anyone uses, they should just be aware of the full licensing agreement.

Answer (score 0):

The standard `Tween` class is kind of stupid in many situations. When using it, you have to be careful that you don't overwrite or remove its instance, as the Garbage Collection could start then. In the same way it always requires you to specify a start value which can lead to disrupting behaviour in the animation.

I'm not exactly sure what exactly your problem is, and with that less code it is hard to reproduce it (you might want to provide a full working example code if you still experience the problem). However I suggest you to try out a different tweening framework. I for myself have made very good experience with [Greensock's TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/). It might have a weird syntax (at least I could imagine a better one), but in general it works really well, and I have solved very many problems with the standard Tween class by simply using TweenLite instead.

Comment: Basically, if the text is showing and I click it or select a part of it, upon clicking the next button (or previous), the text tweens out, but not back in. I'm not sure whether the text tweens out, empties the text and then tweens back in, or, if it doesn't tween back in at all

Comment: Well i will say only one thing that Tween class MUST be deprecated by Adobe. It hangs in many situation as few mentioned by poke.  Greensock's syntax may be little hard but this library is clear winner. It can tween hundreds of objects and never gets hang.